# Remove duplicate values from a dictionary in Swift 3

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift3

Hi I have a dictionary and I just wanna remove duplicate values (with their keys) like so :

```
var myDict : [Int:String] = [1:"test1", 2:"test2", 3:"test1", 4:"test4"]
```

Desired output :

```
[1: "test1", 2: "test2", 4: "test4"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like all the other answers will have O(n^2) performance.

Here is a solution that should operate in O(n) time:

```
var sourceDict = [1:"test1", 2:"test2", 3:"test1", 4:"test4"]

var uniqueValues = Set<String>()
var resultDict = [Int:String](minimumCapacity: sourceDict.count)

//The reserveCapacity() function doesn't exist for Dictionaries, as pointed
//out by Hamish in the comments. See the initializer with minimumCapacity, 
//above. That's the way you have to set up a dictionary with an initial capacity.
//resultDict.reserveCapacity(sourceDict.count)

for (key, value) in sourceDict {
  if !uniqueValues.contains(value) {
    uniqueValues.insert(value)
    resultDict[key] = value
  }
}
```

For small dictionaries the difference is insignificant, but if you have a dictionary with hundreds (or thousands) of key/value pairs then the performance of an n^2 algorithm starts to get **really** bad.

Comment: Thanks @Duncan C  for your remark, I'm actually using a small dictionary so algorithm's complexity is not really important for me. But I will pay attention to It when working with huge dictionaries ! Cheers.

Comment: Just tried your solution, I'm getting an error Value of type '[Int : String]' has no member 'reserveCapacity', maybe initializer signature has changed to something else in Swift 3

Comment: Beware that with N-Squared algorithms the time required starts to grow dramatically at around 30 items. It doesn't take a very large data set for the time required to be noticeable.  See my last comment on Appz' answer.

Comment: `Dictionary` doesn't have a `reserveCapacity(_:)` method (although it really should) – you probably meant to use the `init(minimumCapacity:)` initialiser instead.

Comment: @Hamish, yeah, I realized that when I tried to actually run it, but was too lazy to edit my answer. Thanks for keeping me honest.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myDict: [Int:String] = [1:"test1", 2:"test2", 3:"test1", 4:"test4"]

var result: [Int:String] = [:]
for (key, value) in myDict {
    if !result.values.contains(value) {
        result[key] = value
    }
}

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
let newDict = myDict.keys.sorted().reduce([Int:String]()) { (res, key) -> [Int:String] in
    guard let value = myDict[key], !res.values.contains(value) else { return res }
    var res = res
    res[key] = value
    return res
}
```

> Please keep in mind that dictionary are not sorted so the output could be something like this

```
[2: "test2", 4: "test4", 1: "test1"]
```

---

Please refer to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43307150/1761687) provided by *@Duncan* for a faster solution.

Comment: remember - if you're building up the dictionary dynamically, it's probably better to not add the entry in the first place if you already have it, instead of adding and later removing

Comment: @Russell: Yes, that's what I am doing.

Comment: I believe array.contains(_:) has O(n) performance, so the performance of the whole thing will be roughly O(n^2), which is not good.

Comment: Confirmed. I just wrote a test program that ran your code and my version on a dictionary with 10000 key/value pairs. Your code took  ~23 seconds to run. Mine took ~0.021 seconds, or a little over 1000x faster. The time difference will go up geometrically with the size of the source dictionary.

Comment: I re-ran the test with 100,000 entries in the dictionary and my code took ~0.024 seconds (3 thousandths of a second more than for 10,000 items) and as of this writing the code above is still running, some 10 minutes later. Based on my estimates it will take about 38 minutes. N-squared algorithms are *very* bad for large datasets.

Comment: I let the 100,000 entry test run while I was off on a bike ride. The code from this answer took 49.9 minutes to run, compared to 0.024 seconds for my version.

Comment: @DuncanC I added a reference from my answer to yours. Again, very good idea.

Comment: Hmm. When I re-ran my version on 100,000 entries, I got ~0.16 seconds, which seems more reasonable for 10x as many elements. Not sure how I got 0.024 seconds the first time.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way of doing the same

```
var myDict : [Int:String] = [1:"test1", 2:"test1", 3:"test1", 4:"test4", 5:"test4"]

var newDict:[Int: String] = [:]

for (key, value) in myDict {
    print(key, value)

    let keys = myDict.filter {
        return $0.1.contains(value)
        }.map {
            return $0.0
    }

    if keys.first == key {
        newDict[key] = value
    }
}

print(newDict)
```